# How to change .so files directory generated by ndk-build command?

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I use android studio with ndk and opencv. By default ndk-build command builds files under src/main/libs folder . I want to change it to src/main/jniLibs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the option `NDK_LIBS_OUT=<library output path>` for `ndk-build`.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this through a preference from the build.gradle where the ndk module is defined?